# Issue with Fabric Unity setup. Cannot get past 1st step

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, crashlytics, google-fabric

I've been trying to setup Fabric on my unity project for analytics and fastlane, but it will not get past Step 1 of the setup.

I have Unity 5.6.3f1 and the plugin installation got through without a hitch on Unity, but it's like the dashboard will not recognize the installation.

I also installed (and reinstalled multiple times) Android Studio with the Android SDK and still nothing.

As per the instructions from Unity, I Built my prototype and ran it on my phone and it worked OK, but still no progress on the Setup.

The Android SDK and JDK point to the correct file path on Unity's preferences as well.

I wanted to try to reinstall the Fabric plugin, but the uninstall instructions on the site's knowledge base is only applicable for Macs and I use a PC. I don't have an option to "quit fabric" nor does it appear in my Android SDK plugin list.

I'm not too sure what to do next.

If I'm missing any info, please let me know.

Thanks!

Edit: forgot to add the screenshot

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5G3w.jpg

Comment: Hi! Todd from Fabric. Are you adding Fabric to the first scene? You'll need to, to make sure it initializes. Thanks!

Comment: It was in the scene and everything, but since I redid my project in Unity 2017.2, I tried reinstalling Fabric and this time it worked fine.

I put my android phone as Photo Sharing Mode (instead of File Sharing mode) and had no issues connecting to Fabric after building my project.
I'm guessing that was the issue, so, this ticket can be closed! 

Thank you!